# AWS RDS event subscriptions not triggered

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I created an event subscription has:

- "Target": my-topic
- "Source type": "parameter groups"
- "Parameter groups to include": "All parameter groups"
- "Event categories to include": "Specific event categories [configuration change]"
  [image]

The expected behavior is to see an event and receive an email when someone updates the configuration of a parameter group. After I edit the parameters, there are no events type "parameter groups" and no email from SNS (I'm able to receive emails of another event type.).

Docs for event type: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.Messages.html#USER_Events.Messages.parameter-group

What should I do to see "parameter group" event type?

Comment: Are you changing dynamic or static paramter? If you change a static paramter still don't get an event? Also do you see status active of the rule?

Comment: @Riz I changed both dynamic and static parameters on the first sheet.

Answer (score 1):

I did some tests and I faced the same issue as you. I did some test on `Amazon EventBridge` as well and the issue here is mismatching event details.
The following is the sample event for DB paramter group event as given by aws in Amazon EventBridge.

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "844e2571-85d4-695f-b930-0153b71dcb42",
  "detail-type": "RDS DB Parameter Group Event",
  "source": "aws.rds",
  "account": "123456789012",
  "time": "2018-10-06T12:26:13Z",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "resources": ["arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:123456789012:db:mysql-instance-2018-10-06-12-24"],
  "detail": {
    "EventCategories": ["configuration change"],
    "SourceType": "DB_PARAM",
    "SourceArn": "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:123456789012:db:mysql-instance-2018-10-06-12-24",
    "Date": "2018-10-06T12:26:13.882Z",
    "SourceIdentifier": "rds:mysql-instance-2018-10-06-12-24",
    "Message": "Updated parameter time_zone to UTC with apply method immediate"
  }
}
```

While the following is the event you get when you make any changes to the DB Paramter Group

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "bcbed019-e426-1b4e-0e66-17ef9c1cd4d0",
  "detail-type": "AWS API Call via CloudTrail",
  "source": "aws.rds",
  "account": "xxxx",
  "time": "2022-07-15T15:16:21Z",
  "region": "eu-west-1",
  "resources": [],
  "detail": {
    "eventVersion": "1.08",
    "userIdentity": {
      "type": "AssumedRole",
      "principalId": "xxxx",
      "arn": "xxxx",
      "accountId": "xxxx",
      "accessKeyId": "xxxx",
      "sessionContext": {
        "sessionIssuer": {
          "type": "Role",
          "principalId": "xxxx",
          "arn": "xxxx",
          "accountId": "xxxx",
          "userName": "xxxx"
        },
        "webIdFederationData": {},
        "attributes": {
          "creationDate": "2022-07-15T08:39:39Z",
          "mfaAuthenticated": "true"
        }
      }
    },
    "eventTime": "2022-07-15T15:16:21Z",
    "eventSource": "rds.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "ModifyDBParameterGroup",
    "awsRegion": "eu-west-1",
    "sourceIPAddress": "AWS Internal",
    "userAgent": "AWS Internal",
    "requestParameters": {
      "dBParameterGroupName": "test",
      "parameters": [{
        "parameterName": "default_password_lifetime",
        "parameterValue": "0",
        "isModifiable": false,
        "applyMethod": "immediate"
      }]
    },
    "responseElements": {
      "dBParameterGroupName": "test"
    },
    "requestID": "51917b3f-c08a-4713-a9fe-98da55f090fa",
    "eventID": "a0ddcd12-6ddb-4a4d-a772-89c52abfae0e",
    "readOnly": false,
    "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
    "managementEvent": true,
    "recipientAccountId": "xxxx",
    "eventCategory": "Management",
    "sessionCredentialFromConsole": "true"
  }
}
```

Now you can make an event pattern which can match the above patter(not the sample but the original).

You can use

```
{
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "source": ["aws.rds"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["rds.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["ModifyDBParameterGroup"]
  }
}
```

for your purpose. You can modify this pattern for other purposes as well.

Comment: You use EventBridge to replace RDS Event Subscription to send an alert email, right?

Comment: Yes, As with both RDS event subscription and 'default' eventbrige rule, I wasn't able to receive alert for any change in paramter group.

Comment: I guess this is a bug of RDS Event Subscription.